# Distinguishing Literals from Variables/Symbols in Source Code

Tags: java, string, literals, string-literals

By literals, I means all the constants like

Here 10 is integer literal, 10.5f is floating literal and Hello is a string literal
However after trying something I am successful in some part of code.

```
int a = 10;
float b = 10.5f;
String all = "Hello";

String s = "my source program that i am reading from file";
String lines[] = s.split("\n"); //Break my program into lines
for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
    if(lines[i].contains("="))
    System.err.println(lines[i].substring(lines[i].indexOf("=")+1),lines[i].indexOf(";"));
}
```

but it also provides me the output with assignments like:-

```
Myapp a=new Myapp();
```

However I need to find only literals

Comment: You should use a Java [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), and search through the tokens for literals.  In your example code, you're likely to miss the "\n", "=", and ";" literals.

Comment: Maybe you want to look into http://eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html (although this might be overkill, depending on your concrete need)

Answer (score 1):

While there are better ways to approach this problem, a quick fix in your existing code would be to make a small tweak :

```
    String s = "my source program that i am reading from file";
    String lines[] = s.split("\n"); // Break my program into lines
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].contains("=")) {
            String literal = lines[i].substring((lines[i].indexOf("=") + 1), lines[i].indexOf(";"));
            if (!literal.contains("new"))
                System.err.println(literal);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When running this on itself, it chokes on `if (lines[i].contains("=")) {`, which contains a `=` but not a `;`. I recommend checking for existence of `;` before assuming that it has a positive index.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to find all literals, hook up a java parser or use the "javap" tool to look at the generated class-files. Running it on code that includes these lines:

```
    int a = 20;
    long b = 10L;
    float c = 1.10E12f;
```

And using "grep" to choose only those lines that describe long, float, and String, returns

```
 javap -c Main.class | grep -E "const|push|//" | grep -vE "Field|Method|class"

   0: bipush        20
   2: ldc2_w        #2                  // long 10l
   6: ldc           #4                  // float 1.1E12f
```

This finds *all* literals. Even those inside strings, implicit (`i++`) or somehow quoted. Notice that `int` literals can only be located via the `bipush` and `iconst_*` instructions, as the javap decompiler generates no annotations for them. More on bytecode and constants [here](http://www.artima.com/underthehood/bytecode3.html)

If you are only interested in simple lines of the form `<atomicType> <identifier> = <literal>;` - then search for them using a regular expression:

```
    String pattern = 
        "\\s*\\p{Alpha}[\\p{Alnum}_]*\\s+"  + // type with space, eg.: "int "
        "\\p{Alpha}[\\p{Alnum}_]*\\s*=\\s*" + // java identifier with =, eg.: "myVar ="
        "(([-+]?\\s*\\d*\\.?\\d+([eE][-+]?\\d+)?[Lf]?)?|" + // numeric non-hex
        "(\"[^\"]*\"))\\s*;"; // or unquoted string constant
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        String literal = m.group(1);
        System.err.println(literal);
    }
```